# What is the difference between stdout and stderr in C?

Tags: c, stderr

In C, `stdout` and `stderr` both print to the console window by default. Is there any difference between `stderr` and `stdout` other than the level of buffering?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the differences between `stdout` and `stderr` is the level of buffering.  In [§7.21.3 Files ¶7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p7), the C11 standard says:

> At program startup, three text streams are predefined and need not be opened explicitly -- standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output). As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

Typically, that means that standard output is line buffered (so the data is flushed when a newline is printed, or when the buffer is full), whereas standard error is either line buffered or unbuffered.   These characteristics can be changed, of course.

The purpose of the standard error stream is to separate error messages from regular output.  This is important in contexts such as shell scripts, where the standard output might be sent to a pipe or to a file.  That redirection leaves standard error still going to a different place — usually the terminal.  You can capture the standard output separately from the standard error too, at least if the shell is sufficiently powerful.

```
 program > file
 program | filter
 program 2> error.log | filter
 program > file 2> error.log
 program 2> error.log
```

The first two leave the error messages visible on the terminal.  The last three capture the error messages in the file `error.log` — sending the standard output to the `filter` program, the `file` or to the terminal window respectively.

By separating the error messages from the standard output, the programs down the pipeline (`filter` in my example) don't have to interpret the error messages from `program`, which makes them much, much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

If running a program from the console, or via a batch file, or via a shortcut, use > or 1> to redirect stdout to a file, and use 2> to redirect stderr to a file. For example if reading from stdin, and writing to both stdout and stderr:

```
myprog <input.txt >output.txt 2>error.txt
```

or if you want stdout to a file, but stderr to display on the screen, use:

```
myprog <input.txt >output.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

`stderr` is - well - the place for errors. It is really useful. Like `make` - if a program's return code is not 0 (it completed with errors), it will print `stderr`. `stderr` can not be differentiated from `stdout` by the user, but it's still the recommended place for errors. However, if your program will be run by any automatization program, shell script etc... it can be used to track errors, and *always* use it.

Comment: But now this is wrong or at least unclear: "stderr can not be differentiated from stdout". The two can certainly be differentiated. That's the main point of writing to stdout vs sterr.

Comment: "the place for errors" understates it: stderr is the place for _diagnostic output_. Some things are diagnostic output but not errors, like log messages; those belong on stderr too, unless your program's _purpose_ is to retrieve log messages (which would make them output). Similarly, shell prompts are printed to stderr: they're diagnostic insofar as the (1) aren't output, and (2) exist to provide out-of-band status on the program's state (f/e, whether it's ready for new input).