# Valgrind: Invalid read of size 8, bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd

Tags: c, gcc, struct, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

Have been looking for a simple case as I have on Stack overflow and other sites but still have not found anything, error happens on line 57, then also on line 47, valgrind saying I write a pointer which leads to an array of structures **pixel**, I tried to see, is there a problem with allocating memory, but it seems there is a problem with assignment **bmp_file->data = file_data**

```
==1811== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
==1811== Invalid write of size 8
==1811==    at 0x10BC02: read_bmp (bmp.c:65)
==1811==    by 0x1092D7: main (main.c:12)
==1811==  Address 0x4b97268 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==1811==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1811==    by 0x10BB88: read_bmp (bmp.c:52)
==1811==    by 0x1092D7: main (main.c:12)
==1811== 
==1811== Invalid read of size 8
==1811==    at 0x10BC16: read_bmp (bmp.c:67)
==1811==    by 0x1092D7: main (main.c:12)
==1811==  Address 0x4b97268 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==1811==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1811==    by 0x10BB88: read_bmp (bmp.c:52)
==1811==    by 0x1092D7: main (main.c:12)
```

```
struct bmp_image* read_bmp(FILE* stream) {
  struct bmp_image* bmp_file = (struct bmp_image*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct bmp_image*));
  struct bmp_header* header = read_bmp_header(stream);

  if (header->type != 0x4d42) {
    printf("Error: This is not a BMP file.\n");
    free(bmp_file);
    free(header);
    return NULL;
  }

  struct pixel* file_data = read_data(stream, header);

  bmp_file->header = header;
  bmp_file->data = file_data;

  if (bmp_file->header == NULL || bmp_file->data == NULL) {
    printf("Error: Corrupted BMP file.\n");

    if (bmp_file->header == NULL) {
      free(bmp_file->header);
    }

    if (bmp_file->data == NULL) {
      free(bmp_file->data);
    }

    free(bmp_file);
    return NULL;
  }

  return bmp_file;
}
```

```
struct pixel* read_data(FILE* stream, const struct bmp_header* header) {
  struct pixel* data = (struct pixel*)calloc(header->height * header->width, sizeof(struct pixel));

  if (!data) {
    free(data);
    return NULL;
  }

  fseek(stream, header->offset, SEEK_SET);
  unsigned short padding = header->width % 4;

  for (int pixelIdx = 0; pixelIdx < header->height * header->width; pixelIdx++) {
    data[pixelIdx].blue = (uint8_t)fgetc(stream);
    data[pixelIdx].green = (uint8_t)fgetc(stream);
    data[pixelIdx].red = (uint8_t)fgetc(stream);

    if ((pixelIdx + 1) % (int)header->width != 0 || padding == 0) continue;

    for (int i = 0; i < padding; i++) {
      fgetc(stream);
    }
  }

  return data;
}
```

```
void free_bmp_image(struct bmp_image* image) {
  if (image == NULL) return;

  free(image->header);
  free(image->data);
  free(image);
}
```

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you don’t post screenshots or photos. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I have edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least this memory allocation

```
struct bmp_image* bmp_file = (struct bmp_image *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct bmp_image *));
```

is incorrect. It seems you mean

```
struct bmp_image* bmp_file = (struct bmp_image *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct bmp_image));
```

or

```
struct bmp_image* bmp_file = (struct bmp_image *)calloc(1, sizeof( *bmp_file));
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I am learning now how to allocate memory for structs, and this were my first function where I tried to do this, well, here is where the error was, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid allocation size mistakes:

1. Allocate to the size of the referenced object, not the type.  It makes for cleaner correct code, easier to review and maintain.
2. Cast is unnecessary.
3. Check allocation success.

Example:

```
 // struct bmp_image* bmp_file = (struct bmp_image*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct bmp_image*));
 // wrong size >----------------------------------------------^-----------------------^

 struct bmp_image* bmp_file = calloc(1, sizeof bmp_file[0]);
 if (bmp_file == NULL) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Out-of-memory\n");
   return NULL; 
 }
```

... as well as other allocations in code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you tell me the difference between fprintf(stderr, "Out-of-memory\n"); and prinf(...) ?

Comment: @MarkMinerov Review [What is the difference between stdout and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59799454/2410359).